# RVCM sending error once every week. TibrvException[error=20,message=Invalid subject]

Tags: java, tibco-rv

We're running a trading application with TIBCO RVCM transport (version 5.3) for many years and it's very stable. Recently the application hits the same "Invalid subject" issue once every week, and IT need to manually restart the application to fix this issue. And it causes lots of pains as all the trades need to be manually rebook during the problematic period.

The subject has been used for many years and never changed so it should not be a configuration issue. The application use RVCM in memory ledger. I suspect it may be caused by memory issue by there's no evidence shown so far.

Any hints or debug methods I can use to investigate this problem? Many thanks!

```
TibrvException[error=20,message=Invalid subject]
at com.tibco.tibrv.TibrvImplCmTPortC.natSend(Native Method)
at com.tibco.tibrv.TibrvImplCmTPortC.send(TibrvImplCmTPortC.java:107)
at com.tibco.tibrv.TibrvTransport.send(TibrvTransport.java:144)
at com.tibco.tibrv.TibrvCmTransport.send(TibrvCmTransport.java:168)
```

Comment: We are going to need some more info to debug this.  Does this always happen at the same time or when you run the same job or are there other consistent clues?  What does a tool like Process Explorer (on Windows) or vmstat (on Linux) tell you about memory usage?  I see the problem is being caught in send().  Add some debugging to the application so you capture the outgoing messages and then figure out which one is causing the exception.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! That's the same application running on WebSphere all the time. The memory usage is not high and pretty stable actually. And we have used trace to debug the RV message content which caused this exception, but it's basically the same as other normal messages.

Comment: Also it happens randomly and it's at least once every week(sometimes twice), and it can always be fixed by restart.